# Pointwise convergent, increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, absolute-continuity

If a sequence of increasing, absolutly continuous functions converges pointwise to a function f, does it follow that f is absolutly continuous? What if it converges uniformly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does uniform convergence preserves absolute continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135320/does-uniform-convergence-preserves-absolute-continuity)

Comment: No, it is not duplicate. Here OP required also that each of the function is increasing.

Comment: @user284331 The Cantor function, as mentioned in the linked post, is an increasing function, so it is still a counterexample to OP.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the pointwise convergence it is definitely wrong. For $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}$, $x\in[0,1]$, these are absolutely continuous, but the pointwise limit is not even continuous.

Comment: Cool, but what about when it is uniformly convergent?

Comment: I have no answer, this is the best that I can do so far.

Comment: $f_n(x)=x^n$ is not even an increasing sequence of functions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sequence of increasing functions.

Comment: Increasing sequence of functions VS sequence of increasing functions, I interpreted the OP post as the latter one.

Comment: Ah, it is indeed a sequence of increasing functions. Subtle difference, but a difference nonetheless. I retract my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check Dini's Theorem. An increasing sequence of point-wise convergent functions are automatically converging uniformly

Comment: A funny thing is that, increasing sequence of functions VS sequence of increasing functions, do you see the difference? OP meant the latter, as I guessed.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake here ....